# Server can't handle loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

Alright, I used the following code the generate 10 million different rows,

```
var serverSeed = 'hidden';
var games = 1e7;
var gamesLeft = games;

generateGames();

function generateGames(){
    if(games > 0){
        for(var x = 0; x < 1000; x++){
            serverSeed = genGameHash(serverSeed);
            query('INSERT INTO `hash` SET `hash` = ' + pool.escape(serverSeed) + ', `game` = ' + pool.escape(games-x));
        }   

        games = games - 1000;

        console.log("Progress: " + (100 - games/gamesLeft*100).toFixed(2) + "%");

        generateGames();
    }else{
        console.log('Done generating ' + gamesLeft + ' games.');
    }
}
```

Although from 0.00 to about 20.00% goes fine but then the server returns me an error basically telling me it's out of memory.

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of
>   memory
>       Aborted (core dumped)

I'm generating a hashchain so I need to generate them all in a row, what can I do to still be able to generate the hashchain?

**Query**

```
function query(sql, callback) {
    if (typeof callback === 'undefined'){
        callback = function() {};
    }

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
            if(err) return callback(err);
            connection.release();
            return callback(null, rows);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see an async loop, I do see a recursive loop though and maybe that's creating a huge stack that's causing the error

Comment: You're making 10,000,000 database queries? And you're trying to make them all at the same time? No wonder the server can't handle it.

Comment: @PeterMader not really, I'm excuting a loop right that generates 1k games, then it will launch it again and generate another 1k games and so on, eventually it will reach 10m. or am I doing something wrong here? the server can handle 2million..

Comment: I agree with Peter, why are you trying to generate 10 million games/rows? Are you sure you're architecting this efficiently?? :/

Comment: @MartijnEbbens - yes and no - you loop 1000 times, then recursively call the function to do the next 1000 etc but there's no "waiting" for the 1000 to be done, so, in effect what you're doing is no better than having the for loop do all `10,000,000` - except you're recursing 10,000 deep - which is a lot, and probably breaks you

Comment: tell me ... what is `query` - does it return anything useful?

Comment: @JaromandaX when the query is done..? hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do proper memory allocation and iterate slower:

```
function generateGames(games){
  if(!games) return console.log("done.");
  var serverSeed = genGameHash(serverSeed);
  query('INSERT INTO `hash` SET `hash` = ' + pool.escape(serverSeed) + ', `game` = ' + pool.escape(games),function(){
      generateGames(games - 1);
 });        
}

generateGames(1e7);
```

This creates one queue of insertion, you can add as much as you want:

```
generateGames(1e7/3);
generateGames(1e7/3);
generateGames(1e7/3);
```

Comment: wouldn't this take ages, thanks though I'll try it out.

Comment: @martijn ebbens you could call generateGames(1e7/2) two times. Then it will run twice as fast... ;)

Comment: @martijn ebbens what is *query(...)* ?

Comment: Check post I'll put it there

Comment: @martijn ebbens oh my mistake there was an *-x* still from your code... Should work now

Comment: @martijn ebbems are you shure that your code works??

Comment: Okay, I fixed it by removing var from server seed, but the code doesn't generate 10 million. It stops at 99.99996%

Comment: @martijn ebbens shure? Why do you know that?

Comment: By adding `   console.log(games/gamesLeft*100 + '%')
` to query

Comment: that's 4 short!! how agonising

Comment: @JaromandaX actually, it's not - 100, so it has actually only done 0.00004%

Comment: @martijn ebbens are you shure this isnt a rounding error? And i think the logging is wrong. Whats inside the db?

Comment: @Jonasw it barely even starts.. it does ~0.00004% thats like 400 rows.

Comment: @Jonasw you were right, I messed something up in the database, since I"m just using AI instead of the game count function I removed it but hadn't in the code. 

It's just generating games very slowly now. I'll try to make it faster as you said before, see how that'll work out.

Edit: dividing it by two doesn't make it go faster, it just only stores half the hash's in the database..

Comment: @martijn ebbens you can run it as fast as possible. Just do a few parallel calls and see how your cpu heats up...

Comment: @Jonasw I'm creating a hashchain, if I'd were to divide it by 10 and then run ten of them at the same time, would the hashchain still be correct?

Comment: @martijn ebbens im not shure. And is *slow* maybe *fast enough* already?

Comment: Running 10 at the same time seems to work just fine, it managed to insert 250,000 rows within 120 second(s). I checked if the hash chain is correct by hashing every hash manually and they seem to be correct, I'll let it run for a few more minutes and then check back if it works, if everything works fine I'll accept this an anwser, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you believe you can do 1000 inserts at a time, you can try this

I'm using Promises because Promise.all just makes things like this a lot easier (perhaps because I'm used to using Promises)

```
const pquery = sql => new Promise((resolve, reject) => query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        return reject(err);
    } else {
        resolve(result);
    }
}));
var serverSeed = 'hidden';
var totalgames = 1e7;

function generateGames(games){
    if (games > 0) {
        var batch = Math.min(games, 1000);
        Promise.all(Array.from({length:batch}).map((i, x) => {
            var serverSeed = genGameHash(serverSeed);
            return pquery('INSERT INTO `hash` SET `hash` = ' + pool.escape(serverSeed) + ', `game` = ' + pool.escape(games-x));
        })).then(() => {
            console.log("Progress: " + (100-(games-1000)/totalgames*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
            generateGames(games - 1000);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('done');
    }
}

generateGames(totalgames);
```

Comment: i was always doing Array(n).fill(), looks like another neat trick to confuse OPs... :0